# What are the benefits of using async-await in the background thread?

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency

I'm trying to understand the proper application of `async-await` in Swift. Let's say an `async` method, a non-IO method that doesn't make external calls, is called from a background thread to execute its process, such as some heavy image processing method.

```swift
func processImage(image: UIImage) async -> UIImage {
    ///
}

Task {
   let result = await processImage(image: image)
}
```

1. What is happening when the code is paused and is waiting for the result?  Since it's not making an external call, the process must be done somewhere from within the pool of threads.  And since it's not being done in the very thread the method is called from, it must be being executed on another thread.  Is a subtask created to execute the process?  From what I understand, `Task` is a unit of concurrency and a single task contains no concurrency (except for `async let`), so this is a bit confusing to me.  Is a task concurrent or not concurrent?
2. I understand that if this method is called from the main thread, the non-blocking aspect of the `async` method frees up the thread for the UI elements to run, thereby providing a seamless visual experience.  But, what is the benefit of calling an `async` method from a background thread?  I'm not referring to the syntactic sugar of being able to return the results or throw errors.  Are there any benefits to the non-blocking aspect as opposed to using a synchronous method if the method is a non-IO method called from the background? In other words, what is it not blocking? If it's a parallel process, it's utilizing more resources to process multiple things efficiently, but I'm not sure how a concurrent process in this case is beneficial.

Comment: I suggest you want `Meet async await`. `async await` has little to do with threads and everything to do with actors. You should use never use threads to describe anything with `async await` But should not put an `async` function in the background yourself. You can `detach` from an `actor`.

Comment: Are you referring to the WWDC presentation? Thank you for this. I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, it is a very informative video, they have a couple of more that are related to this subject but that is a very good intro.

Comment: Another note all the old `Queue` such as `DispatchQueue` are not compatible with `async await` you should never mix them, it is one or the other.

Comment: IMO for "heavy image processing" you should concentrate on _how_ it's done, i.e. using CPU, or multiple CPUs,  or GPU, or all of the above. While how the result is delivered (async/await, callback, etc) really depends on convenience for the specific app (i.e. what's the associated UI flow, what else the app is doing, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop thinking in terms of threads if you want to use `async/await`. It is useful, to some extent and for obvious reasons, to keep using phrases like "on the main thread" and "on a background thread", but these are almost metaphors.

You just need to accept that, no matter what "thread" something runs on, `await` has the magical power to say "hold my place" and to permit the computer to walk away and do something else entirely until the thing we're waiting for comes back to us. Nothing blocks, nothing spins. That is, indeed, a large part of the point of `async/await`.

(If you want to understand how it works under the hood, you need to find out what a "continuation" is. But in general it's really not worth worrying about; it's just a matter of getting your internal belief system in order.)

The *overall* advantage of `async/await`, however, is syntactic, not mechanical. Perhaps you could have done *in effect* everything you would do via `async/await` by using some other mechanism (Combine, DispatchQueue, Operation, whatever). But experience has shown that, especially in the case of DispatchQueue, beginners (and not-so-beginners) have [great difficulty reasoning](http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/) about the order in which lines of code are executed when code is asynchronous. With `async/await`, that problem goes away: code is executed in the order in which it appears, as if it were not asynchronous at all.

And not just programmers; the *compiler* can't reason about the correctness of your DispatchQueue code. It can't help catch you in your blunders (and I'm sure you've made a few in your time; I certainly have). But `async/await` is not like that; just the opposite: the compiler *can* reason about your code and can help keep everything neat, safe, and correct.

As for the actual example that you pose, the correct implementation is to define an *actor* whose job it is to perform the time-consuming task. This, by definition, will not be the *main* actor; since *you* defined it, it will be what we may call a *background* actor; its methods will be called off the main thread, *automatically*, and everything else will follow thanks to the brilliance of the compiler.

Here is an example (from my book), doing just the sort of thing you ask about — a time-consuming calculation. This is a view which, when you call its public `drawThatPuppy` method, calculates a crude image of the Mandelbrot set off the main thread and then portrays that image within itself. The key thing to notice, for your purposes, is that in the lines

```
self.bitmapContext = await self.calc.drawThatPuppy(center: center, bounds: bounds)
self.setNeedsDisplay()
```

the phrases `self.bitmapContext =` and `self.setNeedsDisplay` are executed on the main thread, but the call to `self.calc.drawThatPuppy` is executed on a background thread, because `calc` is an actor. Yet the main thread is not blocked while `self.calc.drawThatPuppy` is executing; on the contrary, other main thread code is free to run during that time. It's a miracle!

```
//  Mandelbrot drawing code based on https://github.com/ddeville/Mandelbrot-set-on-iPhone

import UIKit

extension CGRect {
    init(_ x:CGFloat, _ y:CGFloat, _ w:CGFloat, _ h:CGFloat) {
        self.init(x:x, y:y, width:w, height:h)
    }
}

/// View that displays mandelbrot set
class MyMandelbrotView : UIView {
    var bitmapContext: CGContext!
    var odd = false

    // the actor declaration puts us on the background thread
    private actor MyMandelbrotCalculator {
        private let MANDELBROT_STEPS = 200
        func drawThatPuppy(center:CGPoint, bounds:CGRect) -> CGContext {
            let bitmap = self.makeBitmapContext(size: bounds.size)
            self.draw(center: center, bounds: bounds, zoom: 1, context: bitmap)
            return bitmap
        }
        private func makeBitmapContext(size:CGSize) -> CGContext {
            var bitmapBytesPerRow = Int(size.width * 4)
            bitmapBytesPerRow += (16 - (bitmapBytesPerRow % 16)) % 16
            let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
            let prem = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
            let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bitmapBytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: prem)
            return context!
        }
        private func draw(center:CGPoint, bounds:CGRect, zoom:CGFloat, context:CGContext) {
            func isInMandelbrotSet(_ re:Float, _ im:Float) -> Bool {
                var fl = true
                var (x, y, nx, ny) : (Float, Float, Float, Float) = (0,0,0,0)
                for _ in 0 ..< MANDELBROT_STEPS {
                    nx = x*x - y*y + re
                    ny = 2*x*y + im
                    if nx*nx + ny*ny > 4 {
                        fl = false
                        break
                    }
                    x = nx
                    y = ny
                }
                return fl
            }
            context.setAllowsAntialiasing(false)
            context.setFillColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            var re : CGFloat
            var im : CGFloat
            let maxi = Int(bounds.size.width)
            let maxj = Int(bounds.size.height)
            for i in 0 ..< maxi {
                for j in 0 ..< maxj {
                    re = (CGFloat(i) - 1.33 * center.x) / 160
                    im = (CGFloat(j) - 1.0 * center.y) / 160
                    
                    re /= zoom
                    im /= zoom
                    
                    if (isInMandelbrotSet(Float(re), Float(im))) {
                        context.fill (CGRect(CGFloat(i), CGFloat(j), 1.0, 1.0))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private let calc = MyMandelbrotCalculator()
    
    // jumping-off point: draw the Mandelbrot set
    
    func drawThatPuppy() async {
        let bounds = self.bounds
        let center =  CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        self.bitmapContext =
            await self.calc.drawThatPuppy(center: center, bounds: bounds)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    // turn pixels of self.bitmapContext into CGImage, draw into ourselves
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if self.bitmapContext != nil {
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
            context.setFillColor(self.odd ? UIColor.red.cgColor : UIColor.green.cgColor)
            self.odd.toggle()
            context.fill(self.bounds)
            
            let im = self.bitmapContext.makeImage()
            context.draw(im!, in: self.bounds)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID639) defines an asynchronous function as “a special kind of function or method that can be suspended while it’s partway through execution.”

So, this `async` designation on a function is designed for truly asynchronous routines, where the function will suspend/await the execution while the asynchronous process is underway. A typical example of this is the fetching of data with `URLSession`.

But this computationally intensive image processing is not an asynchronous task. It is inherently synchronous. So, it does not make sense to mark it as `async`. Furthermore, `Task {…}` is probably not the right pattern, either, as [that](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5k89c) creates a “new top-level task on behalf of the current actor”. But you probably do not want that slow, synchronous process running on the current actor (certainly, if that is the main actor). You may want a [detached task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/detached(priority:operation:)-8a4p6). Or put it on its own actor.

The below code snippet illustrates how truly asynchronous methods (like the network request to fetch the data, `fetchImage`) differ from slow, synchronous methods (the processing of the image in `processImage`):

```swift
func processedImage(from url: URL) async throws -> UIImage {
    // fetch from network (calling `async` function)

    let image = try await fetchImage(from: url)

    // process synchronously, but do so off the current actor, so 
    // we don’t block this actor

    return try await Task.detached {
        await self.processImage(image)
    }.value
}

// asynchronous method to fetch image

func fetchImage(from url: URL) async throws -> UIImage {
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { throw ImageError.notImage }
    return image
}

// slow, synchronous method to process image

func processImage(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    …
}

enum ImageError: Error {
    case notImage
}
```

For more information, see WWDC 2021 video [Meet async/await in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/). For insights about what `await` (i.e., a suspension point) really means within the broader threading model, [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254) might be an interesting watch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very informative.  It almost seems like `async-await` is actually sequential, but just non-blocking since it waits for the results to occur before the next code happens.

Comment: It's often overlooked, although it’s right there in the name: Async-await is a “concurrency” system. It lets us write simple, linear sequences of code (free of complicated callbacks and closures), while the CPU jumps between multiple logical tasks to achieve concurrency. When we hit an `await`, it suspends that particular path of execution, allowing the CPU to turn to some other task, always making forward progress, never blocking a thread. Now, it can achieve parallelism, too (with separate actors, detached tasks, task groups, etc.), but first and foremost, it is a concurrency system.