# How should I convert a method with a callback queue to async/await?

Tags: swift, async-await, grand-central-dispatch

I want to wrap existing GCD based functions that use both callbacks and callback queues with async/await. I was wondering what pattern I should follow regarding the callback queue. ie:

```swift
// This is what I have
func doWork(completeOn queue: DispatchQueue, completion: (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) { ... }

// I want to wrap this in an async function
func doWork() async throws -> Void {
  try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
    doWork(completeOn: ???, completion: continuation.resume(with:))
  }
}
```

I don't want to be lazy and use `DispatchQueue.main` for the completion queue (and also incur a useless hop to the main queue). What is recommended here? I cannot rewrite the GCD functions.

I'm sure this pattern is frequent enough for a solution to exist, but looking online I could not find much.

Comment: While you're right that using `.main` might cause a hop to the main actor, using any other queue should be fine (don't quote me on this though). Swift concurrency doesn't use dispatch queues, except the main one for `MainActor`.

Comment: Don’t mix dispatch queue and async await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I assume that the second parameter really is a closure.

```swift
func doWork(completeOn queue: DispatchQueue, completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
    …
}
```

Second, I understand your reticence to use `.main` as that might entail a “useless hop to the main queue”. But whatever queue you use, it’s going to entail a useless hop, regardless, because as soon as your `async` method returns, it is going to switch back to one of the Swift concurrency cooperative thread pool’s threads, anyway.

But let’s set that aside for a second. And let us assume for a second that you do not have access to the source for `doWork`. In that case, you are probably putting this method in an extension. And since extensions cannot add stored properties, I would be inclined to add a type property for this queue:

```swift
extension Foo {
    static let completionHandlerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + "Foo.completion") // or `DispatchQueue.global()` or `DispatchQueue.main` or …

    func doWork() async throws {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            doWork(completeOn: Self.completionHandlerQueue, completion: continuation.resume(with:))
        }
    }
}
```

(Obviously, I don’t know what type you are extending, so I used `Foo` as a placeholder.)

Above I picked a serial queue because, depending upon what `doWork` is doing, you might want to protect yourself against races. And I used a custom queue, to avoid burdening (however modest) the main queue. But use whatever queue is most appropriate. Just know, that regardless of which queue you use, you still have a “useless hop.”

Obviously, if you do have access to the `doWork` implementation, it would be ideal to write an `async` rendition of `doWork` that avoids this `DispatchQueue` parameter entirely. That doesn’t necessarily mean changing/breaking the existing GCD interface at all. But you might add a new function that does the `async` rendition without the useless dispatch.

FWIW, while you are probably familiar with it, I might refer future readers to WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/). It walks you through some of the refactoring alternatives (including some of the Xcode refactoring automation).

Answer (score 2):

The bad news - `completeOn` is incompatible with Swift's Structured Concurrency.

Swift makes no guarantee about the thread the execution will continue after an `await` call. One should not make assumptions, or even care about this.

---

The good news - you don't need it.

If `completeOn` was mostly used to deliver on the main thread, use `@MainActor`. If `completeOn` was used to make sure it delivered on some serial queue, to ensure thread safety, use an `actor` instead.

---

As a general rule, avoid mixing GCD and Structured Concurrency, especially if you're in a structured concurrency context. Just let the Swift runtime do the thread management. You might end up with unexpected results otherwise.

---

For your particular case, you could either pass one of the global queues, or change the function to make the `queue` parameter optional and avoid the dispatch if `nil` is passed.

Answer (score 1):

Your second formulation, `func doWork() async throws`, is impossible as a rewrite of your original, because it loses the `completeOn` parameter that specifies the queue. If you want a modern formulation that lets you do that without a completion handler, use Combine.

But even better would be: just toss this whole function out the window and switch to `async/await`. You don't need a callback, you don't need a Result, you don't need to specify a queue, you don't need anything at all. Just do the work! That's the whole point.

```
// some code
let output = try await doAnythingYouLike()
// more code, use output as desired
```

This leaves it up to `doAnythingYouLike` where it wants to run. If you want to ensure that it doesn't run on the main thread, put it in an `actor`. If not, don't put it in an actor and just call it, probably without the `try await`. But the point is, you main code just pauses and waits and resumes coherently without worrying about threads or queues.

In effect, what I'm saying is, in this new world you have to stop thinking about threads and queues! Your original method was built for an outmoded world. Throw it away and learn to think in the newer happier way.

See my https://stackoverflow.com/a/75354516/341994 for a modern formulation for ensuring that a calculation is off the main thread.