# Awaiting value of combine publisher

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a class that manages a websocket connection, it contains some function that sends data to the server:

```swift
func sendRequest() async throws -> // ...
```

Further the class has a `@Published` property `connectionStatus`, which shows if a request can be sent:

```swift
@Published private(set) var connectionStatus: ConnectionStatus = .notConnected
```

If there is no connection (i.e. `connectionStatus` is `.notConnected`), the `sendRequest` function throws. If it is .connected, it runs normally. If `connectionStatus` is `.connecting` however, **I want to wait (`await`?) at the start of the function until `connectionStatus` is either connected or disconnected.**

Is there some simple way, using combine to achieve this behaviour? Basically await until a combine publisher turns on a specific value for the first time.

I don't want to check every time if the server is connected or not before trying to send a request, so I need for the caller to be able to call this function independently of `connectionStatus`.

Comment: Try switching to an AsyncStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the publisher to an `AsyncSequence` using [`values`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/values-1dm9r). Then find the next value it emits using its async iterator.

```
@Published private(set) var connectionStatus: ConnectionStatus = .notConnected

func sendRequest() async throws {
    if connectionStatus == .notConnected {
        throw SomeError()
    }
    if connectionStatus == .connecting {
        var iter = $connectionStatus.values.makeAsyncIterator()
        let next = await iter.next()
        if next != .connected {
            throw SomeError()
        }
    }
}
```

If `sendRequest` is called by another thread, I think it is possible that `connectionStatus` could be changed from `.connecting` to `.connected` after the `connectionStatus == .connecting`, but before `$connectionStatus.values.makeAsyncIterator()`, causing the async sequence to "miss" the `.connected` value. Since values can only be published from the main actor, I'd suggest isolating `sendRequest` to the main actor too.

Comment: I am running into the exact the issue you described with this solution. Is there any other way to handle this than making sendRequest run on the main actor? this is kind of a no-go as the UI would hang for big network requests.

Comment: I have tried adding a @globalActor `@ServerBackgroundActor` but the same issue happened

Comment: @ambassador why would the UI hang? Is this actually happening or is this just something you *think* would happen? Most of the time should be spent asynchronously waiting for a response. The UI shouldn’t hang unless you are doing some CPU intensive work. If that is the case, put that work in a detached task.

Comment: @ambassador you can also try wrapping the critical region in a `MainActor.run` block. In any case, you should find out what code is causing the UI to hang. No code should block any thread in Swift concurrency. If you still struggle, I’d suggest posting a new question, and include the code that is blocking.

Comment: You were right about it being an assumption, as well as it not being an issue, since I now tested it and it does seem to work without hanging! Thanks! Just a small question: why *can values only be published from the main actor*? Also, isn't `MainActor.run` the same thing as `@MainActor`?

Comment: @ambassador "Only publish from main thread" is just a rule that SwiftUI enforces. If you don't publish from the main thread, there will be an error message in the log, and your views probably won't update correctly. `MainActor.run` allows you to only isolate a part of the function to the main actor, rather than the whole function. Because I suspected you had other code in `sendRequest` that would block the UI, I suggested that idea so you can isolate only the `if connectionStatus == .connecting` part to the main actor.

Comment: @ambassador If you *do* have blocking code though, you should call `Task.yield` periodically, in addition to running that in a detached task. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77782898/5133585